# How to check if function is execting at background?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, console, execution

I am working on a PHP Yii project. In this I have a ETL function (in console folder which gets called from frontend controller) which takes more time to execute througly as it calls many dependand functions and executes many stored procedures while execution with logs of the progress of the function execution. On completing the complete execution I am setting success flag in database table and on failure I want to set it as failed. Instead of writing try catch blocks at every required steps and functions, Can we check if a function stopped executing in between so that we can update flag as failed.

**frontend/controller:**

```
$test = exec('php _protected/yii client-integration/run-client>/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!', $output);
        // Return will return non-zero upon an error
        if ($test > 0) {
            print_r($test);
            echo "Success";
        } else {
            print_r($test);
            echo "Failed";
        }
        display($test);
```

$test always returns success(if block) message with process id though I have returned error prone code in console method i.e. in run-client method.

Comment: you are saying that you call the console function from frontend controller, which means you are triggering the job via `exec()` function ? if yes then are you saving the process id to keep track of the process, also `yii\console\ExitCode` have specific exit codes that you can use within your code to see if all went well, but you need to show your code for the console controller,

Comment: i recently did some similar kind of work for exporting large amount of subscribers for the user which started the job from frontend controller using exec and saved the process id and inside the script i keep track of `total `records and `exported` records and keep updating the table **but i do keep a main try catch block** to add any kind of exception to the exception column in the db table so that if not all records are exported i get prompted for the incomplete export job

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, I have updated my post. I guess in case of error exec should return 0 which is not happening in my case. Is it because of >/dev/null 2>&1

Comment: You are running the process in the background which means not return anything to `php` and specifying the `/dev/null 2>&1 &` does that, what you can do is to point to the log file to see the output of the `exec` script and change the `>/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!` to `>/path/to/log/file.log 2>&1 & echo $!` and now the output of the script will be logged to your file.

Comment: And you should save the `ProcessId` for the purpose to check if the job is running in your session to frequently check it in the action and remove once the job completes , you can cehck with `exec("ps -fp $processId", $output);` and then check if the `isset($output[1])` then return it or `return false` in case job is not running any more. it is a pretty wide question and there are alot of things to be addresed that is why i am not adding an answer you should narrow it down.

Comment: Thank you @MuhammadOmerAslam, this one helped me. I did the same thing suggested by you and it worked.